# django-crispy-forms bootstrap 4: How to display checkboxes horizontally?

Tags: django-forms, many-to-many, django-crispy-forms, django-widget, twitter-bootstrap-form

I can't seem to make my CheckboxSelectMultiple widget to display horizontally using django-crispy-forms/bootstrap4.

I've tried :
Specifying it on the form's widgets :
widgets = {'my_field': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'}),}

but the checkboxes still display vertically, and the template renders to this:

`<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="my_field" id="id_my_field_2" value="2"  class="form-check-inline"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_my_field_2">`

This " class="form-check-inline" " is displayed in red.

Same thing happens if I use crispy-forms' helper.
`self.helper.layout = Layout(Field('my_field', css_class="form-check-inline"))`

Any clue why that is? Can someone suggest an alternative?

p.s. : Settings are : CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
Template is :
`{% csrf_token %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% crispy form form.helper %}`

** Edit **
I managed to render them by using:

```
from django_crispy.bootstrap import InlineCheckboxes
self.helper.layout = Layout(InlineCheckboxes('my_field'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import InlineRadios

class DhcpForm(forms.ModelForm):
        cargo = forms.ChoiceField(label='Cargo on Deck',
                          choices=[('true', 'Yes'),
                                   ('false', 'No')]
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        InlineRadios('cargo', id="radio_id"))
```

Comment: Please provide some context or small explanation that goes with the code.

Comment: instead of self.helper.layout = Layout(Field('my_field', css_class="form-check-inline")) try this: self.helper.layout = Layout(InlineRadios('my_field'))

Comment: I meant by editing in your answer for people to understand it

Comment: Thanks Aditi, your answer works for radio buttons. And I found "InlineCheckboxes" which worked for my case. Also added an edit to my question. Couldn't provide much more context though...